# Given $f(x) =x^2+bx+c$, $f(1) = 2$, and $f(-1) = 12$, how do I get $b$ and $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Is there a different way to get $b$ and $c$ values and then the value of $f(2)$?

Here's how my book does it:

Given that
$$f(x) =x^2+bx+c, \qquad f(1) = 2,\qquad f(-1) = 12$$
we see
$$
f(1) = 2 \implies 1^2+b+c=2\implies b+c = 1\\
f(-1) = 12 \implies (-1)^2+b(-1)+c = 12 \implies -b+c = 11
$$
and therefore
$$
b+c = 1, \qquad -b+c = 11.
$$
Thus
$$
2c = 12 \implies c = 6 \implies b = -5
$$

and then

$$
f(2) = 2^2-5\cdot2+6 = 0
$$
$$
f(2) = 0.
$$

I'm sorry if this topic is "too easy". I'm just beginning this math.

(sorry for my bad english, not my native language)

Comment: That would be the way I would do it. I don't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: Is there anything specific that bothers you about this method?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @AlexL: Not really. I'm studying it,and just asked if there's another way to do it. Just to learn.

Comment: Also,what's name of it? Is there really one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this. Just plug in the conditions given... If you're given $f(5)=3$, this means that if you put $5$ in place of $x$, your expression should end up giving you $3$.

You'll need two of these conditions to get $2$ equations having $b$ and $c$ as variables. You solve them simultaneously to get the values of $b$ and $c$.

And then once you have a completely "known" expression for $f(x)$, you can find $f(a)$ for any $x=a$.

Comment: Sorry but I can't upvote your answer. I'm < 15 ruputation. I have a question: Why is -1 subtracted from final result in `b+c=r` where `r` is `=f(x)-1` from expression such as `f(1)=2`. It's in both equations: `b+c=r-1` where `r=f(−1)=12`. So,the expressions became `b+c=1` and `-b+c=11`. Why? should I use in all cases?

Comment: You are given two conditions, namely, $f(1)=2$ and $f(-1)=12$. This means that if you put $1$ in the place of $x$ in the given expression $x^2+bx+c$, the answer should be $2$. Same should be observed for $f(-1)=12$. Applying the first condition $f(1)=2$, we will get $(1)^2+b(1)+c=2$ or $1+b+c=2$. Subtract $1$ from both sides of the equation to get $b+c=1$. Repeat with $f(-1)=12$ to get $-b+c=11$. Now that you have $2$ equations, you just need to add them. This will directly yield the value of $c$ and then of $b$.

Comment: I'll give upvote